# Draw edges through nodes in Graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I am trying to draw a graph using Graphviz in Dot language, and this graph has edges which runs through nodes.

Please see the attached picture below.

So far I did not able to find a way to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated!.

Thanks in advance.
 ( Tips on any other way to render a graph like this would also be really helpful )

[image: Graph with edges going through the nodes]

Comment: While there may be a way to trick graphviz into creating such a picture, I don't think it will be straightforward, and I don't think it's the right tool for this job. Graphviz has some layouts (hierarchical, spring model, radial, circular) and handles automatic layout for these layouts pretty well. For other specialized layouts, using a different tool or rolling your own  may yield better results, especially if you need to repeat it with different inputs.

Comment: @marapet: So there is no possible way of drawing the edges which goes through the nodes in Graphviz. Actually I have tried dozen of other different libraries and Graphviz was the only one that I could find, which can generate graphs at least near to my requirement. But unfortunately, it seems like Graphviz is also unable to render edges like above diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The information above is not that sufficient, however you can check the Drawing with Constrained ranks (Ref: Drawing graphs with dot by "Emden Gansner and Eleftherios Koutsofios and Stephen North").

[Graph with constrained ranks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q9WP.png)

Please read the below for more information :[Drawing graphs with dot](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)

Comment: I have gone through above mentioned doc, and still I cannot find a way to render edges which cross through the nodes.

Comment: That's not an answer, rather a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today, this worked for me in `layout=dot`.

(1) setting `splines` to `false`
(2) have the specific edge attribute `constraint` set to `false`, for edges which must go through another node.

```
splines=false
x -> y [constraint=false]
```

Be aware it only worked OK because I did not use a `label` for the `edge`.
Using the `edge` attributes `taillabel` and `headlabel` worked for me.